# TypeScript: Decorating a derived class with typed decorator function

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-decorator, typescript-class

I am trying to build an "Entity Framework"-like ORM library for node.js and MongoDB with TypeScript.

With this library, the consumer will be able to define a Model class (ex. `Person`) that will extend a `Base` class, and the class decorator will add additional data to the Person class (for example, `instances` array, that will contain all the Model's instances, and `collection_name` that will be the MongoDB collection name for the model, etc.).

Code in [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Base%3CT%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09static%20collection_name%3A%20string%0D%0A%09static%20instanes%3A%20Base%3Cany%3E%5B%5D%0D%0A%09_id%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IClass%3CT%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09new()%3A%20Base%3CT%3E%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09instances%3A%20Base%3CT%3E%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%09collection_name%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20decorator%3CT%3E(config%3A%20%7B%20collection_name%3A%20string%20%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20function%20%3CT%20extends%20Base%3CT%3E%3E(Class%3A%20IClass%3CT%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09Class.collection_name%20%3D%20config.collection_name%3B%0D%0A%09%09Class.instances%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%09return%20Class%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%40decorator%3CPerson%3E(%7Bcollection_name%3A%20'people'%7D)%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%3C%3D%3D%3D%3D%20ERROR%0D%0Aclass%20Person%20extends%20Base%3CPerson%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FError%3A(25%2C%202)%20TS2345%3A%20Argument%20of%20type%20'typeof%20Person'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'IClass%3CBase%3C%7B%7D%3E%3E'.%0D%0A%2F%2F%09Property%20'instances'%20is%20missing%20in%20type%20'typeof%20Person'%20but%20required%20in%20type%20'IClass%3CBase%3C%7B%7D%3E%3E'.%0D%0A).

---

So my first step was creating a `Base` class:

```
class Base<T>
{
    static collection_name: string
    static instances: Base<any>[]
    _id: string
}
```

So the user will be able to define his model like so:

```
@decorator<Person>({collection_name: 'people'})
class Person extends Base<Person>
{
    @field name
    @field address
    ...
}
```

then I created a decorator class to set the `collection_name` and `instances` properties on the Person class:

```
function decorator<T>(config: { collection_name: string }) {
    return function <T extends Base<T>>(Class: IClass<T>) {
        Class.collection_name = config.collection_name;
        Class.instances = [];
        return Class
    }
}
```

the decorator function receives the user-generated `Class`, and I am trying to create an interface that will describe the type of such class. I called it `IClass`:

```
interface IClass<T>
{
    new(): Base<T>

    instances: Base<T>[];
    collection_name: string
}
```

- `new` is the constructor (that returns a `Base` instance)
- `instances` and `collection_name` are static properties of `Base<T>` and are non-static here (I'm not sure about this, is this right?)

However, when trying to define the user Model I get the following error:

```
@decorator<Person>({collection_name: 'people'})   // <==== ERROR HERE ===
class Person extends Base<Person>
{
}
```

> Error:(23, 2) TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof Person' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'IClass>'.
>
> Property 'instances' is missing in type 'typeof Person' but
>   Type 'typeof Person' is missing the following properties from type
>   required in type 'IClass>'.

It seems like the typescript compiler is ignoring the static members inherited from `Base` when checking the type of `typeof Person`.

How can I define the type of the Class property of the decorator function ?

Comment: `type PersonConstructor = typeof Person;` then use `@decorator<PersonConstructor>`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks for your comment for your edit. 
but... nope that didn't do the trick, still the same error. 
also, the Person class is a user-defined class, so I'm trying to keep the syntax as simple, short and usable as possible

Comment: Fair enough, hadn't tried it, just looked like that might have been the trick looking at your initial error. Let me see if I can actually get your example working and I'll let you know.

Comment: Your immediate problem is that `decorator()` returns a function that only accepts constructors that are *already* of type `IClass<T>`... but you're trying to take *any* constructor and *return* an `IClass<T>`, right?

Comment: I found a solution that works, jcalz is right. I'm posting an answer right now. You need to split your interface into two in order to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem [as jcalz points out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54950970/1541563#comment96665240_54950970) is that your decorator is accepting a `Class` of a type that *already* has the static properties `instances` and `collection_name`. You need to use two different interfaces, one which is a type that simply constructs instances of `T` with the `new(): T` signature, and another that extends this interface to include the static properties your decorator will add.

```
class Base<T> {
    static _id = 0;
    private _id: number;

    constructor () {
        this._id = Base._id++;
    }
}

interface BaseConstructor<T extends Base<T>> {
    _id: number;
    new(): T;
}

interface DecoratedBaseConstructor<T extends Base<T>> extends BaseConstructor<T> {
    instances: T[];
    collection_name: string;
}

function decorator<T extends Base<T>>(config: { collection_name: string }) {
    return (baseConstructor: BaseConstructor<T>): DecoratedBaseConstructor<T> => {
        const decoratedBaseConstructor = baseConstructor as Partial<DecoratedBaseConstructor<T>>;
        decoratedBaseConstructor.collection_name = config.collection_name;
        decoratedBaseConstructor.instances = [];
        return decoratedBaseConstructor as DecoratedBaseConstructor<T>;
    };
}

@decorator<Person>({collection_name: 'people'})
class Person extends Base<Person> {
    name: string;

    constructor () {
        super();
        this.name = 'foo';
    }
}
```

With this approach, all of `Base`'s `static` members must be public. Any `static` members of `Base` initialized in the decorator should go in the `DecoratedBaseConstructor`, and any remaining `static` members not initialized in the decorator should go in the `BaseConstructor` instead.

I assume that you use the generic type `T` in the `Base` class somehow in your actual code, but if you don't, you should remove the generic type from the `Base` class and everything else will still work the same.

Check out the above snippet [in this playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMA8AVAfNA3gKGn6EALmIQJbDQD6pAJtALzQAMA3LvgA4BOpAbiQiq0AXNAB2AVwC2AIwRc27PMAD2YolwnBCKrtAAUASixL8eQgAtSEAHTU6jeBAR3aAajdszAX2y-spGKE8gBmYMCCTggAwmoaWjpcqNAIAB7BYjQwUahoGDhm9qKSsvJe+GIIAO5Goihs-oHBXGER0AAiCKpcAjRRseqEmtq6yWkZWXCIuRjjCJnZiAPxI0noJmaBRGBiERB1ANoAuuXKKiAgXWRqlGJgUgiiGoEA5g3Y2CESu9di0DRdXQkUYoFLpeaTHLoND6VRiEKkF6iTDQVQXK6kG53B5PIavaDeYwFfBcBCECRcP76GRLOJDBK6UT9OnDRK5QyiTrdXrMwaskEYej5UxmOFEf6AnrBPq0vkMvSMGnOZb01bQSDQAAKYC4ZDAICQXKB0t5KzZ0NOZgl3JNsrNuhsaMu2kxYlu90EjDhCJejvOzt+7oelrMAJtCBlypZ8psW2IuwQMEYxxDJLJFL+YeNEdNqsS6pgRqlObteYFlu872wAAEs1LRpr5BA1DDME6MViPaIAOQcBAqDiXbuE7CgSAwRtcZt-OYLKbOJCT6fCszYx4EPFiN4fUXRtVGDZWvAQCR9rhGVPmKy2NcMaDdkIqFTdit+IA).

Comment: thanks, this is great and did the trick! I still need to sharpen my TS skills :)

Comment: @PatricRoberts
I'm afraid this solution has a glitch...
when the user extends the Person class, DecoratedBaseConstructor is no longer assignable to it.
gist: https://gist.github.com/rotemx/b6509599c6f3c0d4d4098dd0a3a4be93

Comment: @PatricRoberts what about the behavior implementation in Base class? this is where the actual code is, like save(), update(), etc.

Comment: or should i just implement everything in the decorator ?

Comment: @rotemx would you mind telling me why this answer doesn't work for you _again_?